# Setting Coordinates in VLC media player

Tags: media-player, media, vlc

I want to open multiple instances of VLC Media player side by side.

How can I set the co-ordinates on Windows? I couldn't find anything in the VLC Command Line, is there a way I can launch these, and pass some positions using Windows parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools > Preferences or press [CTRL + P].

```
Under the currently selected Interface preference, find the heading that says Playlist and Instances.
Make sure that Allow only one instance checkbox is not checked.
```

To open a second player window, we just have to click on any shortcut which is used to access the software. Search for and click on the VLC menu item from the start menu and it will open a new one. Similarly, you can also simply right-click on the current VLC icon in the task bar and click on VLC Media Player to open a new one.

Get more instructions [here: http://filejunkie.org/download/vlc_media_player.html](http://filejunkie.org/download/vlc_media_player.html)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it via the user interface. Just write a batch/shell script that contains:

```
vlc.exe --no-one-instance --no-embedded-video --video-x=50 --video-y=50 videofile.mp4
```

If you want to disable the window borders just add:

```
--no-video-deco
```

And to set the window size use:

```
--width=640 --height=480
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: If this is not working for you then you probably hit this bug - https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/9931